# .iso to .img permission denied

Tags: system-installation

Im trying to make a bootable USB thumbdrive with ubuntu 13.10 on a mac. Im getting "Permission denied" at step 3, converting a .iso to an .img . I've set all the permissions to read & write. with no luck. Any Ideas Anyone?

Just like this guy......When I copy and paste the download into terminal and then copy and paste the example after it, it should comvert from an iso file to an img file. It just says on terminal 'permission denied'. Not sure what to do.

For Clarity When I'm referring to item #3

[How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick#Manual_Approach)

1. Download the desired file
2. Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight)
3. Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil

   ```
   hdiutil convert /path/to/ubuntu.iso -format UDRW -o /path/to/target.img
   ```

I've tried a few different permutations My result is always "permission denied".

Answer (score 2):

I've always had to place sudo in front of that command:

```
sudo hdiutil convert /path/to/ubuntu.iso -format UDRW -o /path/to/target.img
```